# mod_rewrite and CSS

Tags: css, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to change all the URLs on a site. Example: `http://www.site.com/about/` becomes `http://www.site.com/?action=about` (don't worry, I have nice friendly sanity checking). The problem is that for anything other than `http://www.site.com/` the CSS stylesheet won't load. I assume this is because it looks for the stylesheet in `/about/content/style.css` instead of `/content/style.css`. How do I make sure it finds the right stylesheet?

Here's some of my code just in case. `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ /?action=news&start=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/?$ /?action=news&start=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^(about|contact|man|home|download)/?$ /?action=$1 [L]
```

They all redirect to `index.php`, which starts off like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use an absolute URI for your CSS file?  ie /content/style.css.  Saves headaches like this.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be setting the base URI using the `BASE` HTML element:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Thereby relative URIs are resolved from the base URI path `/` and not the URI path of the current ressource (in your case `/about/`).